# Textfield displaying incorrectly in Angular2 with Material Design Lite

Tags: angular, material-design

In my Angular2 app I have an issue with textfields showing the default blue border when placing the curser in the textfield.

You can find a demonstration of this in the [simple Plunkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Thvo8mYuscHC3zLko6hX?p=preview) using the default material light textfield HTML.

```
<div>
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample1">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample1">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Any clues on why this is?

Comment: Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/XofqusYpD0v50FqRBvC8?p=preview See `style.css`. I guess angular2 material package doesn't have styles for this behavior

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I just copied my example from the official Material Design Guide: https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section. That seems to work. Is it something Angular2 specific?

Comment: I was wrong. You don't use angular2 material. In your app material script doesn't work properly as it works in official Material Design Guide http://take.ms/DMCdx

Comment: Here is official repo for angular2 material https://github.com/angular/material2

Comment: For your plunker calling `componentHandler.upgradeAllRegistered()`  after template loading should solve your problem https://plnkr.co/edit/6t7oVxYWg0OXO1XUNObk?p=preview (See `ngAfterViewInit` inside component) But anyway for angular2 i advice you to choose the official repo fo angular2

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks!